# np.where to update row values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am pulling information from a database and the `location` information comes back as GeoJSON.  What I want to do is use `np.where` to apply a transformation on the pandas' dataframe to each row value.  Can this be done instead of using apply?

Here is the `np.where` I am using:

The gist is this: If a value in location is null ensure it stays NULL, else convert the value to the Shapely Geometry object.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import shape

class Geometry():
   def __init__(self, data):
      self._j = shape(data)

dummy_data = [{'_key': '42741', '_id': 'points/42741', '_rev': '_a6hqTXS-BI', 'location': {'coordinates': [-73.9942131, 40.7152034], 'type': 'Point'}, 'name': 'Lao Di Fang Noodle House'}, {'_key': '51156', '_id': 'points/51156', '_rev': '_a6hqTb6-_8', 'location': {'coordinates': [-73.9939157, 40.7154794], 'type': 'Point'}, 'name': '68 Deli Canal Store'}, {'_key': '42994', '_id': 'points/42994', '_rev': '_a6hqTXe--g', 'location': {'coordinates': [-73.9952133, 40.716076], 'type': 'Point'}, 'name': "Popeye'S Chicken & Biscuits"}, {'_key': '45769', '_id': 'points/45769', '_rev': '_a6hqTZC-_W', 'location': {'coordinates': [-73.9937748, 40.715124], 'type': 'Point'}, 'name': '27 Sheng Wang Noodle Shop'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data)

df.location = np.where(df.location.isnull(), np.nan, Geometry(df.location.values))
```

I know this does not work, but I want to take advantage of the speed of `numpy` for these transformation processes.

Any advice/suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Maybe use a list comprehension instead?

Comment: `np.where()` can be applied here. However, I think the class `Geometry` is not working for you as expected because if you use `np.where(df.location.isnull(), np.nan,0)`, it works  perfectly.